# Generic List and Generic Array

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest alternative to a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383888/what-is-the-easiest-alternative-to-a-generic-array-in-java)

I have the following code:

```
class B<X>
{
    public void create()
    {
        List<X> l1 = new ArrayList<X>(); //No ERROR

        X[] arrr = new X[10];   //ERROR
    }
}
```

I know that I cannot instantiate a Generic array due to type erasure. But why can I instantiate an instance of a generic List?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the easiest alternative to a generic array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383888/what-is-the-easiest-alternative-to-a-generic-array-in-java) or (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626867/generic-class-to-array-of-generics-of-same-generic-type)

Comment: I think I understand the question. If `new ArrayList<X>();` is essentially treated as `new ArrayList<Object>();` due to type erasure, why is `new X[10];` not handled like `new Object[10];`? - or vice-versa, if Java can't handle the array, how can it handle the list?

Comment: @Alan, Thank you. That is what I was asking.

Comment: @Lukas Eder...I completely disagree that it is a duplicate question. I am asking **why** can we create a Generic List instance but not a generic array instance.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that generics are implemented using type erasure:

No type `X` is known at runtime. That means that you can't instantiate an array of that (unknown type).

But since you don't need (and in fact can't use) the type information for creating a parameterized type at runtime (again: type erasure), creating an `ArrayList<X>` is not a problem.

Note that internally an `ArrayList` **always** uses an `Object[]` for actual storage, no matter what the type argument is.

Answer (score 0):

Angelika Langer provides excellent documentation on Java generics. This link answers your question about the difference between Lists (and other generic types) and arrays and *why* you cannot instantiate arrays in this way:

http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104

In short: Because arrays are covariant, it is **not type safe** to instantiate an array of a parameterized type.